# How to dismantle this mixer tap?

Tags: faucet, taps

I have this kitchen sink mixer tap, which is leaking from where the neck meets the main body, whenever it's turned on, (either hot or cold).

So what I'm trying to do is remove the neck so that I can get at the inside, to possibly replace an O-ring or something. However, I can't seem to find any way of removing it.

[image: Front view]

I found a small screw at the back, which I removed, however this didn't make any difference. The neck can swivel around 360 degrees no problem, but when I tried to wiggle it or pull it loose (as described by many online tutorials), it wouldn't budge.

[image]

Are there any other things that might need to be done to take this off?

Comment: can you turn that little ring? Suspect it either unscrews or snaps off.  (and seriously price out a new one before investing too much time/effort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Disconnect your water lines (after turning the water off of course).
2. Remove your Water Handles.
3. Remove the cartridge from inside the unit, there might be a Circlip retainer in the inner side of the cartridge area.

Comment: I tried removing the handles and the chrome cone shapes you can see attached to the handles, and yes indeed i was able to wiggle the neck free! Don't know why, though, because I couldn't see anything of what I removed that was attached to the neck...